# Objective-C Getter Memory Management

Tags: objective-c, memory-management

I'm fairly new to Objective-C and am not sure how to correctly deal with memory management in the following scenario:

I have a Core Data Entity with a to-many relationship for the key "children". In order to access the children as an array, sorted by the column "position", I wrote the model class this way:

```
@interface AbstractItem :  NSManagedObject  
{
    NSArray * arrangedChildren;
}

@property (nonatomic, retain) NSSet * children;
@property (nonatomic, retain) NSNumber * position;
@property (nonatomic, retain) NSArray * arrangedChildren;

@end


@implementation AbstractItem

@dynamic children;
@dynamic position;
@synthesize arrangedChildren;

- (NSArray*)arrangedChildren
{
    NSArray* unarrangedChildren = [[self.children allObjects] retain];
    NSSortDescriptor* sortDescriptor = [[NSSortDescriptor alloc] initWithKey:@"position" ascending:YES];
    [arrangedChildren release];
    arrangedChildren = [unarrangedChildren sortedArrayUsingDescriptors:[NSArray arrayWithObject:sortDescriptor]];
    [sortDescriptor release];
    [unarrangedChildren release];
    return [arrangedChildren retain];
}

@end
```

I'm not sure whether or not to retain unarrangedChildren and the returned arrangedChildren (first and last line of the arrangedChildren getter). Does the NSSet allObjects method already return a retained array? It's probably too late and I have a coffee overdose.

I'd be really thankful if someone could point me in the right direction. I guess I'm missing vital parts of memory management knowledge and I will definitely look into it thoroughly.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`-allObjects` returns an autoreleased instance, there is no need to retain and release it.

As for `arrangedChildren`, it will be retained only if you use the synthesized setter:

```
self.arrangedChildren = [unarrangedChildren sortedArrayUsingDescriptors:/*...*/];
```

Directly assigning to the instance variable as you do does not invoke the synthesized setter.

Finally, you shouldn't retain the return value here - your method isn't named starting with `alloc`, `new` or `create` and callers thus have to [take ownership explicitly](http://developer.apple.com/mac/library/documentation/cocoa/Conceptual/MemoryMgmt/Articles/mmObjectOwnership.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/20000043-SW1).

I recommend reading the ["Cocoa Memory Management Guide"](http://developer.apple.com/mac/library/documentation/cocoa/Conceptual/MemoryMgmt/MemoryMgmt.html) and the section on ["Declared Properties"](http://developer.apple.com/mac/library/documentation/cocoa/conceptual/objectivec/articles/ocProperties.html) in the Objective-C language description.

Comment: I just read through your link to the Object Ownership and Disposal chapter of memory management and I think I understand now. I guess I need to read the whole guide again, as I'm sure I missed alot the first time.
Very useful answer! Thanks!

Comment: Given that you never read the ivar, it seems pointless to have it at all.  Make the property readonly and the variable `arrangedChildren` local to the method.  Then, as Georg says, don't retain/release unarrangedChildren nor retain arrangedChildren.  And you can lose the `@synthesize...` too.

Answer (score 0):

The `retain` in your @property for arrangedChildren should take care of that. You will need to `release` it in your dealloc.

Comment: Thanks for the hint, I forgot to copy the dealloc method to the post as I left out the rest of the class.